# Did I blow my 1998 civic up?

Tags: honda, civic, leak, smoke

Driving on the interstate and I notice a heavy cloud of smoke following me. I pull over to shoulder and see that it is coming from under hood. Being a female, I didn't open hood immediately but, continued to smoke steadily for at least ten minutes, gradually decreasing.  When I did pop the hood, I discovered that oil had been blown all over the left side of engine. There was puddle that had formed  underneath stretching about 2 feet or so from the car.

Any insight as to the cause?

I am totally lost.

Comment: What color was the fluid which you found under the car? I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest your issue is either your engine or your transmission, most likely the transmission. If the engine was still running good when you shut it down, white smoke like you are talking about is usually associated with transmission fluid.

Comment: How did the car drive prior to smoke?  Was it still shifting properly (assuming it's an automatic for now)?  How did the steering feel?  Any strange noises while driving?  Was smoke coming out of the tailpipe or only from under the hood?  Can you localize any smells (it feels strange to sniff under the car but it can help)?

Comment: I have a feeling @Kat isn't going to respond.  Unregistered user.